# Getting error while running selenium test in node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

The code I am using to run the automated test for google search is below.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');


driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');

driver.sleep(10000).then(function() {
  driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.TAB);
});

driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();

driver.sleep(20000).then(function() {
  driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
      console.log('Test passed');
    } else {
      console.log('Test failed');
    }
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

and it is throwing an error which says that element is not interactable. I have added extra time delays for loading page successfully.

```
(node:32241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

**element not interactable** is telling you that the element you are trying to click on - is just not clickable.

You have 2 ways to overcome this:

1. Find the child element of the element you are trying to click on or its parent element.
2. Force the element to be clicked by injecting JavaScript into it:

   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName
   ('btnK')[0].click();");

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of adjustments as follows:

- Remove the first occurance of `findElement(By.name('q'))` as you are already using the line of code later.
- Modify the second occurance of `findElement(By.name('q'))` to send the text and *`Key.RETURN`*
- Remove the line `findElement(By.name('btnK'))` as you are already using the line of code later.
- Your effective line of code will be:

  ```
  const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .build();

  driver.get('http://www.google.com');

  driver.sleep(10000).then(function() {
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver' + Key.RETURN);
  });

  driver.sleep(20000).then(function() {
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
      if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
        console.log('Test passed');
      } else {
        console.log('Test failed');
      }
      driver.quit();
    });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `driver.findElement()` return promise,

So it can be anywhere in your code, so basically you have sync your code
may be here:

```
:driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();
```

so you need to make your code sync. just put ==>

```
await driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();
```

-> this method won't work. Because you do not know browser behaviour  some time it is fast and sometimes slow so this won't help you, `driver.sleep()`.

Better to use:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementedlocated(By.xpath("xpath"),5000));
```